# Auto filter with sheet name and Delete Hidden rows

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

i want to Delete data from excel based on a filter. filter data based on sheet name with specified column ex col A, and delete Hidden value.

my intention to keep the data based on the sheet name, i have tried with loop but it take long time for processing.

```
wb.Activate
wb.Sheets("PMCC 1").Select
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    index = index + 1
    If index <= 10 Then
        irow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        newtemp = Replace(ws.Name, " ", "#0")
        For J = irow To 2 Step -1
            If ws.Cells(J, 1) <> newtemp Then
                ws.Cells(J, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next J
    Else
        irow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        newtemp = Replace(ws.Name, " ", "#")
        For J = irow To 2 Step -1
            If ws.Cells(J, 1) <> newtemp Then
                ws.Cells(J, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next J
    End If

Next ws

MsgBox ("Deleted")
```

Comment: You should show us some code first. What I would do if I were you. Go to developer ribbon -> record macro -> start recording -> filter the sheet but using the sheet name as filter to hide the data you want -> delete the data which is not hidden -> stop recording -> check the code

Comment: Writing a requirement is not asking a question see [ask] (there is no question in your post). Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify & try this solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, Index As Long, j As Long
    Dim newtemp As String

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Index = Index + 1

        With ws

            If Index <= 10 Then

                newtemp = Replace(.Name, " ", "#0")
            Else
                newtemp = Replace(.Name, " ", "#")

            End If

            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                For j = LastRow To 2 Step -1

                    If .Cells(j, 1) <> newtemp Then
                        .Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
                    End If

                Next j

        End With

    Next ws

    MsgBox ("Deleted")

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried above code but it is taking long time.. i have modified code